# How to show only a image name instead of complete image path

Tags: html, vue.js

Here while I am uploading a image. The path is displaying "C:\fakepath\promotion1.JPG". So here I want to remove this fakepath. Because of this fakepath image is  not uploading in my project media folder. So How to solve this issue. Instead of a complete path i want to capture only image name. Please help me to solve this issue

```
<div>
   <img src:"previewImage" class="uploading-image" />
   <input type="file" accept="image/jpeg" @change=uploadImage>
</div>
```

**vue.js**

```
<script>
    export default {
        name:'imageUpload',
        data(){
            return{
               previewImage:null
            }
        },
        methods:{
            uploadImage(e){
                const image = e.target.files[0];
                const reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsDataURL(image);
                reader.onload = e =>{
                    this.previewImage = e.target.result;
                    console.log(this.previewImage);
                };
            }
        }
     }  // missing closure added
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to resolve `C:\fakePath` for the actual file path on the filesystem, but that's prevented for the user's security.

From [`<img>` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#value):

> The string is [prefixed with `C:\fakepath\`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#fakepath-srsly), to prevent malicious software from guessing the user's file structure.